# Map nested JSON in Azure Data Factory to raw object

Tags: json, azure-data-factory

Since ADF (Azure Data Factory) isn't able to handle complex/nested JSON objects, I'm using OPENJSON in SQL to parse the objects. But, I can't get the 'raw' JSON from the following object:

```
{
   "rows":[
      {
         "name":"Name1",
         "attribute1":"attribute1",
         "attribute2":"attribute2"
      },
      {
         "name":"Name2",
         "attribute1":"attribute1",
         "attribute2":"attribute2"
      },
      {
         "name":"Name3",
         "attribute1":"attribute1",
         "attribute2":"attribute2"
      }
   ]
}
```

**Config 1**

When I use this config: [image]

I get all the names listed

1. Name1
2. Name2
3. Name3

Result:

[image]

**Config 2**

When I use this config:

[image]

I get the whole JSON in one record:

1. [ {{full JSON}} ]

Result:

[image]

**Needed config**

But, what I want, is this result:

1. { "name":"Name1", "attribute1":"attribute1", "attribute2":"attribute2  }
2. { "name":"Name2", "attribute1":"attribute1", "attribute2":"attribute2  }
3. { "name":"Name3", "attribute1":"attribute1", "attribute2":"attribute2  }

Result:

[image]

So, I need the iteration of Config 1, with the raw JSON per row. Everytime I use the $['rows'], or $['rows'][0], it seems to 'forget' to iterate.

Anyone?

Comment: If you are frustrated with ADF's pure lack of multi-collection selection when it comes to parsing JSON, Please upvote this: https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/23432697-7026-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f032c

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Data Flows to handle JSON structures? We have that feature built-in with data flow transformations like derived column, flatten, and sink mapping.

Comment: I've tried Data Flows previously, but not yet for this case. I will give it a try! Besides that: doe you know if it's possible at all in a regular ADF pipeline?

Comment: I'm not sure what is wrong with Data Flows.. I've tried several things, but I can't even display the Preview Data for the sample JSON above. 'Fetching data 'is spinning all the time, and I got several errors (CommandAsync issues). Is that normal?

Comment: Try creating a new dataset in the Data Flow source and do not include the schema in the dataset. You can import the schema in the data flow source.

Comment: I've tried a lot, but somehow it doesn't work like it should (I assume). My sample file is just a few bytes in size, and has a validated JSON structure, with only three lines (as you can see in the question). Still, the 'Test Connection' takes about 1 minutes, and the 'Import Schema' takes forever, and then results in an error: GetCommandOutputAsync failed with (<-- blank!). I really want to give it a try, but it's working against me. I've tried to refresh my session, turn debug on/off, but nothing seems to work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The copy active can help us achieve it.

For example I copy `B.json` fron container "backup" to another Blob container "testcontainer" .

This is my `B.json`  source dataset:

[image]

**Source:**

[image]

**Sink:**
[image]

**Mapping:**

[image]

**Pipeline executed successful:**

[image]

**Check the data in testcontainer:**

[image]

Hope this helps.

---

**Update:**

Copy the nested json to SQL.

Source is the same `B.json` in blob.

**Sink dataset:**

[image]

**Sink:**

[image]

**Mapping:**

[image]

**Run pipeline:**

[image]

**Check the data in SQL database:**

[image]

Comment: Although I really appreciate the work you put into the answer, I already showed this as my Config 1. You've managed to map the individual columns and put them in a new JSON. I want to map to a SQL table, for which each record contains the full raw json for one row. Do you have an idea how to do that?

Comment: @TJ_ Please see my update. If my answer is helpful for you, you can mark it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: Again, sorry for all the work, but I think you don't understand what I want. apparently I have not explained it correctly. I've added some SQL screenshots, to make myself clear. Hope it will work.

Comment: @TJ_ I'm sorry. I tried and according my experience, we can not copy the nested json array to the SQL as json string.

Comment: There is a little checkbox "Map complex values to string", this allows for the data to be copied as raw json, but I don't think you can use a array as the source. I managed to do the copy after outputting each record as a file, then all the files become the source.